# Prove that there exists $B$ such that $\mu(f(B))>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. $f(B)$ is measurable for every Borel set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $\{y:f^{-1}(y) \text { is infinite}\}$ has measure $0$. Suppose there is some $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ and $\mu (f(A))>0$. Prove there is a closed set $F$ such that $\mu(F)=0$ and $\mu(f(F))>0$.

My try:

$\mu(f(A))>0$ implies that there exists a subset $C$ of $A$ such that $f(C)$ is not measurable. I try to find a closed set $B$ such that $C\subset B$ and $\mu(B)=0$. Then we can get $\mu(f(B))>0$. However, I don’t know how to find such $B$.

Comment: My intuition is that, to construct a nasty closed set of zero measure, you want to use something like the Cantor process: start with something too big (like the closure of A, perhaps) and repeatedly remove open sets you don't need. Sorry if that route ends up leading to a dead end.  :/

Comment: Maybe start with some toy examples, like let $f$ take the integers to intervals, i.e. $n \mapsto (n-\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2})$ and see how you can generalize this.

Comment: the set $\{y:f^{-1}(y) \text { is infinite}\}$ doesn't make so much sense because $f$ is real-valued.

Comment: It would be sufficient to show that the function $B \mapsto \mu(f(B))$ is inner regular. The tricky thing is that this function is not a measure. However it still has nice properties: it is what some people call a capacity. I suggest to take a look at exercise 8.4.7 and the proof of theorem 8.4.1 in Cohn's measure theory book. Be warned that this is probably overkill though...

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Thank you very much for your reference!

Comment: @Masacroso I think it should be read as $y$ such that the cardinality of $f^{-1}(y)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer:**

Consider $C(A)=\mu(f(A))$. Three things can be checked:

1) $C(\emptyset)=0$.

2) If $A\subseteq B$, then $C(A)\leq C(B)$.

3) If $E_{1}\subseteq E_{2}\subseteq\cdots$, then $C\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}E_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}C(E_{n})$.

We wish to have the following extra condition:

4) If $K_{1}\supseteq K_{2}\supseteq\cdots$ are compact, then $C\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}K_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}C(K_{n})$.

If the fourth condition is also met, then Choquet Theorem shows that $C$ is capacitable in the sense that each Souslin set, in particularly, Borel set, is inner regular.

Now we can find a Borel set $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$ such that $\mu(B)=0$, then we also have $\mu(f(B))\geq\mu(f(A))>0$.

As $C$ is capacitable for $B$, so a compact set $K\subseteq B$ is such that $C(K)>(1/2)C(B)>0$, then of course $\mu(K)=0$ and $\mu(f(K))>0$.

The point is that, given any compact set, is there a way to show that $\mu(f(K))<\infty$? If so, then the fourth condition is met. Note that I haven't used the assumption that $\{y: f^{-1}(\{y\})~\text{is an infinite set}\}$ is measure zero. I think this may be crucial for the fourth condition to be met.

If the above proposal fails, naturally, one may ask, if this question holds for the measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(f(K))=\infty$ for some compact set $K$?

**Edit:**

Let $\mathbb{R}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$, where $(X_{n})$ is disjoint with positive measure. Consider 
\begin{align*}
\nu(S)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\dfrac{\mu(S\cap X_{n})}{\mu(X_{n})}.
\end{align*}
Then $\nu$ is a finite measure and $\nu<<\mu$ together with $\mu<<\nu$.

We construct the capacity with respect to $\nu$, not $\mu$.

Now for every $y\in\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}f(K_{n})-N$, then $y=f(x_{n})$ for $x_{n}\in K_{n}$. The sequence $(x_{n})$ cannot have any subsequence with consists of mutually distinct elements, for then it will violate $y\notin N$ and hence $(x_{n})$ must be eventually constant. So $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}f(K_{n})-f\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}K_{n}\right)\subseteq N$.

With such, we have 
\begin{align*}
C\left(\bigcap_{n}K_{n}\right)&=\nu\left(f\left(\bigcap_{n}K_{n}\right)\right)\\
&=\nu\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}f(K_{n})\right)-\nu\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}f(K_{n})-f\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}K_{n}\right)\right)\\
&=\nu\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}f(K_{n})\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\nu(f(K_{n}))\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}C(K_{n}).
\end{align*}
Therefore the fourth condition is met. We can now apply Choquet Theorem.

Note that we at first have only that 
\begin{align*}
\nu(f(K))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\dfrac{\mu(f(K)\cap X_{n})}{\mu(X_{n})}>0.
\end{align*}
But then we may choose an $N$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\dfrac{\mu(f(K)\cap X_{n})}{\mu(X_{n})}>0.
\end{align*}
We see that 
\begin{align*}
\mu(f(K))&\geq\mu\left(f(K)\cap\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}\right)\right)\\
&=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}(f(K)\cap X_{n})\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu(f(K)\cap X_{n})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\dfrac{\mu(f(K)\cap X_{n})}{\mu(X_{n})}2^{n}\mu(X_{n})\\
&\geq\gamma\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\dfrac{\mu(f(K)\cap X_{n})}{\mu(X_{n})}\\
&=\gamma\nu(f(K))\\
&>0,
\end{align*}
where $\gamma=\min\{2^{n}\mu(X_{n})\}_{n=1}^{N}>0$.

Comment: I think you can ignore infinities simply by replacing $C$ with $\max(C ,1)$ throughout. This is because you are only looking for a set of positive measure, not to find a good approximation of $\mu(f(A))$. Also, you are right that the assumption on preimages implies condition 4. This is because you always have $f( \cap K_n) \subset \cap f(K_n)$, and the difference between those 2 sets is contained in the set of points with infinite preimage.